# Type Mismatch when looping through sheets to paste array into range

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a function that pastes a month and year into a series of sheets. However, for some reason, the code errors out at the following line: 
    Worksheets(RepName3).Range("R2:AC2") = ary
The error message is "Type Mismatch", however you can see that earlier in the Sub I paste the array into a different range, ws.Range("B3:M3"). That portion works fine, so I think it must be something to do with the way I reference each new worksheet. However, I use that system of looping through the worksheets in different subs with no issues. Any advice as to what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

```
Sub Finish_Numbers()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
Dim ary() As Variant, RepName3 As Variant, RepList3 As Variant
ary = Array("Jan-", "Feb-", "Mar-", "Apr-", "May-", "Jun-", "Jul-", "Aug-", 
"Sep-", "Oct-", "Nov-", "Dec-")
Dim yr As Integer

yr = Year(Now)

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Reps")
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 2
Set RepList3 = ws.Range("A3:A" & (LastRow + 2))

ws.Range("B3:M3") = ary

With ActiveWorkbook
For Each RepName3 In RepList3
    Worksheets(RepName3).Range("R2:AC2") = ary
    For i = 18 To 29
        Worksheets(RepName3).Cells(2, i).Value = 
Worksheets(RepName3).Cells(2, i).Value & yr
    Next i
Next RepName3
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheets(RepName3.Text)` should fix this. Also you're not really using your `With ActiveWorkbook ... End With` - to do so, you should have a `.` in front of each `Worksheets` within.

Comment: @BigBen That did the trick, thanks!

Comment: `RepName3` is a `Variant/Range`, whose `Value` may contain an `Error` value. Assuming this value can be implicitly converted to a `String` is a very common mistake, and throws a *type mismatch* every time. Declare it `As String` and see if the error moves up to the assignment itself. If it does, see if `IsError(ws.Range("A3:A" & (LastRow + 2)))` returns `True`.